# TypeInitializationException when running my application with Caliburn.Micro.Platform on Win 7?

Tags: caliburn.micro

I have an application that runs fine on my Win 8.1 development machine but when I go to install it on my Win 7 64 bit test box I run into a TypeInitializationException with Caliburn.Micro.Platform.  What could be causing this?  the error log that leads me to believe it is Caliburn.Micro is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<WERReportMetadata>
    <OSVersionInformation>
        <WindowsNTVersion>6.1</WindowsNTVersion>
        <Build>7601 Service Pack 1</Build>
        <Product>(0x30): Windows 7 Professional</Product>
        <Edition>Professional</Edition>
        <BuildString>7601.18409.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.140303-2144</BuildString>
        <Revision>1130</Revision>
        <Flavor>Multiprocessor Free</Flavor>
        <Architecture>X64</Architecture>
        <LCID>1033</LCID>
    </OSVersionInformation>
    <ParentProcessInformation>
        <ParentProcessId>2356</ParentProcessId>
        <ParentProcessPath>C:\Windows\explorer.exe</ParentProcessPath>
        <ParentProcessCmdLine>C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE</ParentProcessCmdLine>
    </ParentProcessInformation>
    <ProblemSignatures>
        <EventType>CLR20r3</EventType>
        <Parameter0>MyApp.exe</Parameter0>
        <Parameter1>0.6.25.0</Parameter1>
        <Parameter2>546dfbc7</Parameter2>
        <Parameter3>Caliburn.Micro.Platform</Parameter3>
        <Parameter4>2.0.1.0</Parameter4>
        <Parameter5>53f41236</Parameter5>
        <Parameter6>92</Parameter6>
        <Parameter7>0</Parameter7>
        <Parameter8>System.TypeInitialization</Parameter8>
    </ProblemSignatures>
    <DynamicSignatures>
        <Parameter1>6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48</Parameter1>
        <Parameter2>1033</Parameter2>
        <Parameter22>2b5c</Parameter22>
        <Parameter23>2b5cea20275728230acc663702d2e8da</Parameter23>
        <Parameter24>5bd8</Parameter24>
        <Parameter25>5bd8dc1fa50918888316b6b5f643c5e9</Parameter25>
    </DynamicSignatures>
    <SystemInformation>
        <MID>BA765621-6E94-49A3-BF5C-4CA9CB339779</MID>
        <SystemManufacturer>Microsoft Corporation</SystemManufacturer>
        <SystemProductName>Virtual Machine</SystemProductName>
        <BIOSVersion>090006</BIOSVersion>
    </SystemInformation>
</WERReportMetadata>
```

Comment: what version of the .NET framework is installed on the Win7 Box?

Comment: 4.5.2, confirmed in the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And you are building against .NET 4.5, and you have the assemblies all correctly referenced. The one that tends to pop out is the Interactivity assembly, it gets buried hard to detected. Since it is a .NET usually version changes between Windows version. Can only suggest it is missing or a version number needed mismatch. Make sure the one from the lib folder in your packages from nuget is present on the install of your WIN7 box. If that is how you got the CM framework. otherwise pull the latest github release